# Why d3.scaleLinear domain impacts bars offset in V4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I am drawing my first bar chart in d3.js, and quite surprised with the scaleLinear() impact on the bars position.

First I define the scale as:

```
      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0,100])
      .range([0,300]);
```

Here is the result:
[image: chart with domain=100]

Actually, the domain is too large, 20 is sufficient. so I set:

```
      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0,20])
      .range([0,300]);
```

Here is the result:
[image: chart with domain=20]

The bars are longer, which is correct, but they were pushed down, which is not. Here after is the complete script embedded in a Ruby on Rails 5.0 partial.

Can someone explain this behaviour and help me to solve the issue?

Thanks a lot.

The complete script:

```
  <script>
      // Progression data

     var errors = <%= d3_chart_series_for(this_object).map { |measure| {index: measure.idx, count: measure.score}}.to_json.html_safe   %>;
  // Returns an array of hashes
  //       var errors = [{"index":"2017-01-14","count":"5.35"},{"index":"2017-01-15","count":"2.24"},{"index":"2017-01-16","count":"1.55"},{"index":"2017-01-17","count":"5.11"},{"index":"2017-01-18","count":"2.96"},{"index":"2017-01-19","count":"4.62"},{"index":"2017-01-20","count":"6.71"},{"index":"2017-01-21","count":"9.47"},{"index":"2017-01-22","count":"8.15"},{"index":"2017-01-23","count":"9.25"},{"index":"2017-01-24","count":"5.35"}];

     var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([
          new Date(Date.parse('<%=history_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")%>')),
          new Date()
          ])
      .range([0,500]);

      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0,100])
      .range([0,300]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisTop(x)
      .ticks(10);

      var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y)
      .ticks(5);

      var graph =  d3.select('#progression')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 650)
      .attr('height', 400);

      var bars = graph.selectAll('rect')
      .data(errors);

      var newBars = bars.enter();

graph.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,50)")
    .call(xAxis);

graph.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(600,50)")
    .call(yAxis);

newBars.append('rect')
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
    .attr('x',function(d, i) {
      return x(Date.parse(d.index));})
    .attr('y',y(20))
    .attr('height', function(d,i) {
      return y(d.count);})
    .attr('width', 20 )
    .attr('fill', d3.scale.category20());

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
.attr('y',y(20))
```

When you do this for setting the `y` position of the bars you're not defining a fixed position, but a position that varies according to the domain. So, every time you change your domain, `y(20)` is mapped to a different value in the range.

Check this:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([50, 300]);

console.log(y(20));//returns 100

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 20])
    .range([50, 300]);

console.log(y(20));//returns 300
```

**Solution**: set the top of the bars to same y position of the x axis, which is 50 in your code:

```
.attr('y', 50)
```

If you want a padding, just add something to that value.

Here is a demo, with the y domain going from 0 to 20, as you requested:

```js
var errors = [{"index":"2017-01-14","count":"5.35"},{"index":"2017-01-15","count":"2.24"},{"index":"2017-01-16","count":"1.55"},{"index":"2017-01-17","count":"5.11"},{"index":"2017-01-18","count":"2.96"},{"index":"2017-01-19","count":"4.62"},{"index":"2017-01-20","count":"6.71"},{"index":"2017-01-21","count":"9.47"},{"index":"2017-01-22","count":"8.15"},{"index":"2017-01-23","count":"9.25"},{"index":"2017-01-24","count":"5.35"}];

var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

errors.forEach(function(d){
d.index = parse(d.index);
});


     var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(errors, function(d){ return d.index}))
      .range([0,500]);
   

      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0,20])
      .range([50,300]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisTop(x)
      .ticks(10);

      var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y)
      .ticks(5);

      var graph =  d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 650)
      .attr('height', 400);

      var bars = graph.selectAll('rect')
      .data(errors);

      var newBars = bars.enter();

graph.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,50)")
    .call(xAxis);

graph.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(600,50)")
    .call(yAxis);

newBars.append('rect')
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
    .attr('x',function(d) {
      return x(d.index);})
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('height', function(d,i) {
      return y(d.count);})
    .attr('width', 20 )
    .attr('fill', "teal");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**PS**: bars and time scales don't mix very well... you can see that the bars *start* at the precise date, but their width makes them finishing at a wrong date. Move them to the left or, a better alternative, use another scale (as a band scale).